# How to render a string as an erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How can I render a string like erb files render.

for example I want this string:

```
"Hello <%= 'World'%>"
```

To be:

```
"Hello World"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I properly understand you, this would be helpful:

```
require 'erb'
str = "Hello <%= 'World'%>"
result = ERB.new(str).result  # => "Hello World"
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use variables:

```
require 'erb'
w = "World"
str = "Hello <%= w %>"
result = ERB.new(str).result(binding)  # => "Hello World"
```

Comment: This is great, But what if in the string there are variables. Can I pass these variables ?

Comment: Sure, but you have to use instance variables instead of local variables. I've updated my post.

Comment: I got some weird problem. This code works for me in the console, but it doesn't work when I run it on a controller.

Comment: What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: It doesn't receive the variables. It prints only "Hello" (without the "World"). It says that @w is nil.

Comment: Ok, got it. There are no mysterious things :) We've forgot about such wonderful thing as binding - please look at updated snippet in post above

Comment: This does indeed work, however I'm a little confused how you knew to use the word `binding`. Also, to clear up any confusion, this code belongs in the controller, not another ERB file.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this. I render an ERB from a string, as shown in this answer, and in that string I'm looping over an array and calling a partial view to display each item in the array (`<%= render "my_partial_view", :item => current_item` - for instance). But in the partial view, I get an error saying that `item` is not defined. This worked fine when I was using concrete views. Any ideas?

Comment: How would you define binding?

Comment: For info on the binding keyword : Binding is from ruby core : https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Binding.html